# What file is mounted on loop0?

Tags: mount, loop-device

Today I noticed that some time in the past I mounted an ISO, but forgot which one it was:

```
/dev/loop0 on /export/production/os/iso/centos/mount type iso9660 (rw)
```

How can I find the exact file name that is mounted on /dev/loop0?

Answer (score 10):

```
losetup /dev/loop0
```

produces something like:

```
/dev/loop0: [000f]:8070558 (/path/to/file.iso)
```

`losetup` comes with the `util-linux` package.

Answer (score 4):

`losetup -a` will probably tell you what you need